# plural or singular after "what": "What movie(s) do you want to watch?" asked Ella

Tags: singular-vs-plural

1. What movie do you want to watch?" asked Ella.
2. What movies do you want to watch?" asked Ella.

Which one is good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how many movies in a row you are planning to watch with Ella. I mean if you are going to spend the weekend at home watching sci-fi movies or if you are in a film festival and expect to watch more than one movie, it's plural. If you just want to pick a single movie, it's singular. It does not depend on the particle "what".